# WPF Drag/drop buttons in between text

Tags: wpf, button, text, drag

I need to make a functionality in which you have to be able to make a template for a piece of text. You need to be able to enter hard text and placeholders. The idea is that you can enter text like you would in any textbox control and also drag buttons in the control that represent placeholders for e.g. names or age. Is it possible to both enter text and drag/drop buttons within the same control?

I already found the Devexpress ButtonEdit control, but that control doesn't let you order the buttons in between the text. I was also thinking about using just buttons and make them editable, but that might be a little less convenient for the user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is posible with an [InlineUIContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inlineuicontainer(v=vs.110).aspx)  and `RichTextBox`

```
private void RichTextBox_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox tb = ((RichTextBox)sender);
    var b = new Button();
    b.Content = "Placeholder";
    var container = new InlineUIContainer(b, tb.CaretPosition);
    container.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Center;
    tb.CaretPosition = container.ElementEnd;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: hhmm... thanks for you answer, but now I got the problem that the richtextbox events arent firing :S. I didn't use them before. Any idea why they don't fire?

Comment: @SebastiaanHoedeman that's strange.. I have no ideas right now, sorry, but I'll let you know when I have any

Comment: Oh never mind, they work now, don't know what went wrong :S. I'll finally try you answer now :).

Comment: It works! Thank you very much and have a nice christmas in advance! :D

Comment: Still a little question. The text and buttons combination in the richtextbox works nicely, but once the buttons are in there I can't drag and drop them anymore (if I would like to switch to buttons for example). I can just do it manually for the InlineUIContainers, but is there a better way to be able to drag the embedded InlineUiContainers around?

Comment: @SebastiaanHoedeman just a guess, are buttons enabled inside a RichTextBox? If not, try to set RichTextBox's property IsDocumentEnabled to true, maybe this would help. Can't say more as I'm kind of far away from my laptop :(

Comment: Yeah I did that already, but that just enables the buttons. It doesn't allow drag/drop OOTB. I did it manually which also works fine, so I'll just go with that. Thanks for your help.